# How do I restore back to Ubuntu 18:04 from Kali?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04

I was previously running Ubuntu 18:04, when I recently and accidentally edited the `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` by adding (recalling from memory) 2 lines, similar to: `deb http://http.kali...` that I found on some site. I also stupidly added a few other lines of code that I can not remember.

Now, Whenever I boot my computer, rather than the usual Ubuntu showing, I am met with this menu.
[image: First image I see on boot]

When I choose the ***Kali GNU/Linux**. I get stuck and can't go beyond this point illustrated in the image:
[image]

To fix this issue, I attempted to drop to the root shell prompt via the `Advanced option for Kali GNU/Linux` as illustrated below:

[image]
The intention was to edit the `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` by commenting out or deleting lines starting with: `deb http://http.kali...`, however, as seen in the image, the root account seems to be locked. Pressing enter to continue leads to this page:

[image]

How do I restore Back to Ubuntu 18:04 from Kali?

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Apt & package tools are designed to upgrade to the latest version of packages found in your sources. If you add a source that will provide later packages (including a different system), you'll change your known system into a frankensystem (no longer anything specific but a mix of packages). Packages are designed to go to later/newer automatically, but it's a rather manual process to reverse, so it's easier to just restore your system from backups, or re-install. You can explore your logs to see what was upgraded (ie. what you need to reverse), but it's somewhat manual.  Re-install is easier.

Comment: @guiverc unfortunately, I have a lot of valuable unbackup data on the laptop. Kindly point me in the right direction to manually restoring the Ubuntu OS. Luckily I have a dual boot of Windows 10 which I am able to start normally. Does this help in anyway?

Comment: As I stated, explore the logs and look at what was installed after you added the *kali* repositories. Those packages need to be re-installed. You can view command history to see when you did things (if you use commands like I do & have commands record date & time), otherwise timestamp of changes to sources will likely tell you. Use a *live* system (Ubuntu install media) to explore details, and backup your data, then `chroot` to your installed system to fix).  You're looking at hours-days (depending on your skill level) to correct & the change(s) you made.

Comment: As you're asking how, in my view you're risking more damage and my suggested re-install is easier, faster & achieves the same thing. Details as to what was changed (unknown) are needed to fix.  You can install Ubuntu desktop without risk to data (you should always have backups as mistakes are easily made), via *something-else*, using existing partitions & ensuring you don't format your partition. It'll note packages, erase system directories, install, then add-back your additional packages (if available in Ubuntu repos) without touching user data/configs (desktop) as long as you don't install.